# Raspberry Pi Python button gives false positives

Tags: python, multithreading, button, raspberry-pi, false-positive

Can someone point me in the correct direction of how to fix this issue with the false positives I recieve?

I have tried to do according to this suggestion (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/63512/how-can-i-detect-how-long-a-button-is-pressed) but to no avail. I still get those random false positives that ruin everything I have worked for these past two weeks.

I have added the entire code for clarity (but relevant parts are down).

```
###################################
# Control program
###################################
# LCD            R Pi                

# RS             GPIO 26 (pin 37)        
# E              GPIO 19 (35)
# DB4            GPIO 13 (33)
# DB5            GPIO 6  (31)
# DB6            GPIO 5  (29)
# DB7            GPIO 11 / SCLK (23)

# WPSE311/DHT11  GPIO 24 (18) 

# Relay Fog      GPIO 21 (40)
# Relay Oxy      GPIO 20 (38)
# Relay LED      GPIO 16 (36)

# Button Killsw. GPIO 12 (32)

# F1 (Therm.)    GPIO 4  (7)   - Gul kabel
# F2 (Fogger)    GPIO 25 (22)  - Blå kabel
# R  (Root)      GPIO 24 (18)  - Lila kabel
# G  (Grow area) GPIO 23 (16)  - Brun kabel
# P  (Bar . SCL) GPIO 3  (5)   - Grön kabel (OBS! Går via I2C)
# P  (Bar . SDA) GPIO 2  (3)   - Grå kabel  (OBS! Går via I2C)




###################################
# Imports--- [ToDo: How to import settings from a configuration file?]
###################################

import adafruit_dht, board, digitalio, threading, os, glob 
import adafruit_character_lcd.character_lcd as characterlcd
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import adafruit_bmp280
import logging
import time
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep, perf_counter
from gpiozero import CPUTemperature
from datetime import datetime




###################################
# Definitions---
###################################

# Compatible with all versions of RPI as of Jan. 2019
# v1 - v3B+
lcd_rs = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D26)
lcd_en = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D19)
lcd_d4 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D13)
lcd_d5 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D6)
lcd_d6 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D5)
lcd_d7 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D11)

# Define LCD column and row size for 16x2 LCD.
lcd_columns = 16
lcd_rows    = 2

# Define relays
relay_fogger = 21 #digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D21) #- Why does this not work?
relay_oxygen = 20 #digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D20) #- Why does this not work?
relay_led    = 16 #digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D16) #- Why does this not work?

# Define liquid nutrient temperature probe
liquid_nutrients_probe = 23 #digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D23) - Why does this not work?

# Define the killswitch push button
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)




###################################
# Initializations
###################################

# Init file log
#logging.basicConfig(filename=datetime.now()+'.log', format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)
#logging.basicConfig(filename='Logging.log', format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)


# Init the lcd class---
lcd = characterlcd.Character_LCD_Mono(lcd_rs, lcd_en, lcd_d4, lcd_d5, lcd_d6, lcd_d7, lcd_columns, lcd_rows)

# Init thermometer for liquid nutrients fluid
os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')
base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[0]
device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'

# Initialise the BMP280
i2c = board.I2C()
# For some strange reason, the default address of the BMP280 is 0x76 when checking all via 'i2cdetect -y 1' whereas default expects 0x77.
# Thus are we forcing the address to correpsond correctly with below line of code."""
bmp280 = adafruit_bmp280.Adafruit_BMP280_I2C(i2c, address=0x76)

# Init DHT22 sensors---
dhtDevice_nutrient_mist = adafruit_dht.DHT22(board.D23, use_pulseio=False)
dhtDevice_roots_chamber = adafruit_dht.DHT22(board.D24, use_pulseio=False)
dhtDevice_grow_area = adafruit_dht.DHT22(board.D25, use_pulseio=False)

# Init relays---
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(relay_fogger, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(relay_oxygen, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(relay_led, GPIO.OUT)




###################################
# Global variables---
###################################
killswitch = False
display_info_delay = 5 # Seconds

# Fogger bucket variables
temp_nutrient_solution = 0
temp_nutrient_mist = 0
humidity_nutrient_mist = 0
fogger_on_seconds = 2700 #45 min
fogger_off_seconds = 900 #15 min
sleep_fogger = False

# Grow bucket variables
temp_roots = 0
humidity_roots = 0
pressure_roots = 0
temp_grow = 0
humidity_grow = 0

# Oxygen bucket variables
sleep_oxygen = False

# Rapsberry Pi internal temperature
rpi_internal_temp = 0

# DHT22 error status variables
dht_fog_chamber_error = False
dht_root_chamber_error = False
dht_grow_area_error = False


###################################
# Methods---
###################################

def button_callback(channel):
    """When the button is pressed."""
    global killswitch
    # Due to serious issues with false positives regarding button being pushed
    start_time = time.time()
    
    while GPIO.input(channel) == 0: # Wait for button up
        pass
    
    buttonTime = time.time() - start_time
    
    if buttonTime >= .1:
        print("###########\nKillswitch button was pressed!\n###########")
        killswitch = True

# Init the button
GPIO.add_event_detect(12, GPIO.RISING, callback=button_callback, bouncetime=150)
#GPIO.add_event_detect(12, GPIO.FALLING, callback=button_callback, bouncetime=500)


def read_temp_raw():    
    """Help function for the thermometer readings."""
    f = open(device_file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines


def get_temp_nutrient_solution():
    """Measure the temperature of the nutrient solution where the ultrasonic fogger is."""
    global killswitch
    while killswitch==False:
        global temp_nutrient_solution
        
        lines = read_temp_raw()
        while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
            time.sleep(0.2)
            lines = read_temp_raw()
        equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
        if equals_pos != -1:
            temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
            temp_nutrient_solution = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        
        # For development process
        print(
            "F1 Temp nutrient solution: {:.1f} C / {:.1f} F".format(
                temp_nutrient_solution, c2f(temp_nutrient_solution)
            )
        )
        sleep(1)


def get_temp_humidity_nutrient_mist(): 
    """Measure the temperature and humidity of the nutrient mist where the ultrasonic fogger is."""
    global killswitch
    while killswitch==False:
        try:
            # Update global temp value and humidity
            global temp_nutrient_mist
            global humidity_nutrient_mist            
            temp_nutrient_mist = dhtDevice_nutrient_mist.temperature
            humidity_nutrient_mist = dhtDevice_nutrient_mist.humidity
            
            # For development process
            print(
                "F2: {:.1f} C / {:.1f} F Humidity: {}% ".format(
                    temp_nutrient_mist, c2f(temp_nutrient_mist), humidity_nutrient_mist
                )
            )
 
        except RuntimeError as error:
            # Errors happen fairly often, DHT's are hard to read, just keep going
            print("Warning (DHT fog): " + error.args[0])
            sleep(2) # sleep(1) for DHT11 and sleep(2) for DHT22
            pass
        except Exception as error:
            global dht_fog_chamber_error
            print("DHT fog sensor fatal error!")
            dht_fog_chamber_error = True
            dhtDevice_nutrient_mist.exit()
            raise error
     
        sleep(2)


def get_temp_humidity_grow_area(): 
    """Measure the temperature and humidity of the grow area."""
    global killswitch    
    while killswitch==False:
        try:
            # Update global temp value and humidity
            global temp_grow
            global humidity_grow           
            temp_grow = dhtDevice_grow_area.temperature
            humidity_grow = dhtDevice_grow_area.humidity
            
            # For development process
            print(
                "Grow area: {:.1f} C / {:.1f} F Humidity: {}% ".format(
                    temp_grow, c2f(temp_grow), humidity_grow
                )
            )
 
        except RuntimeError as error:
            # Errors happen fairly often, DHT's are hard to read, just keep going
            print("Warning (DHT grow): " + error.args[0])
            sleep(2) # sleep(1) for DHT11 and sleep(2) for DHT22
            pass
        except Exception as error:
            global dht_grow_area_error
            print("DHT grow sensor fatal error!")
            dht_grow_area_error = True
            dhtDevice_grow_area.exit()
            raise error
     
        sleep(2)


def get_temp_humidity_root_chamber(): 
    """Measure the temperature and humidity of the roots chamber."""
    global killswitch    
    while killswitch==False:
        try:
            # Update global temp value and humidity
            global temp_roots
            global humidity_roots           
            temp_roots = dhtDevice_roots_chamber.temperature
            humidity_roots = dhtDevice_roots_chamber.humidity
            
            # For development process
            print(
                "Root chamber: {:.1f} C / {:.1f} F Humidity: {}% ".format(
                    temp_roots, c2f(temp_roots), humidity_roots
                )
            )
 
        except RuntimeError as error:
            # Errors happen fairly often, DHT's are hard to read, just keep going
            print("Warning (DHT root): " + error.args[0])
            sleep(2) # sleep(1) for DHT11 and sleep(2) for DHT22
            pass
        except Exception as error:
            global dht_root_chamber_error
            print("DHT root sensor fatal error!")
            dht_root_chamber_error = True
            dhtDevice_roots_chamber.exit()
            raise error
     
        sleep(2)


def get_pressure_root_chamber():
    """Gets the pressure from the BMP280 device. This device can also measure temperature (more precise than DHT22) and altitude. """
    global killswitch
    while killswitch==False:
        #temperature = bmp280.temperature()
        global pressure_roots
        pressure_roots = bmp280.pressure
        # For development process
        print(
            "Pressure roots: {:.1f} hPa ".format(
                pressure_roots
            )
        )
        #print('Pressure: {} hPa'.format(pressure_roots))
        sleep(2)


def relay_fogger_control():
    """Fogger on for 45 min and off for 15. Perpetual mode unless kill_processes() is activated"""
    global killswitch
    global fogger_on_seconds, fogger_off_seconds
    
    while killswitch==False:
        GPIO.output(relay_fogger, GPIO.HIGH)
        sleep(10)
        #sleep(fogger_on_seconds)
        GPIO.output(relay_fogger, GPIO.LOW)
        sleep(10)
        #sleep(fogger_off_seconds)


def relay_heatled_control():
    """Heat LED controller. When is it too hot for the crops? Sleep interval? Perpetual mode unless kill_processes() is activated"""
    global killswitch
    global led_on_seconds, led_off_seconds
    
    while killswitch==False:
        GPIO.output(relay_led, GPIO.HIGH)
        sleep(20)
        #sleep(led_on_seconds)
        GPIO.output(relay_led, GPIO.LOW)
        sleep(10)
        #sleep(led_off_seconds)

def relay_oxygen_control():
    """Oxygen maker. Perpetual mode unless kill_processes() is activated or barometric pressure is too high."""
    global killswitch
    while killswitch==False:
        GPIO.output(relay_oxygen, GPIO.HIGH)
        sleep(15)
        #sleep(oxygen_on_seconds)
        GPIO.output(relay_oxygen, GPIO.LOW)        
        #sleep(oxygen_off_seconds)
        sleep(25)
   

def reset_clear_lcd(): 
    """Move cursor to (0,0) and clear the screen"""
    lcd.home()
    lcd.clear()
    

def get_rpi_temp(): 
    """Get Rapsberry Pi internal temperature"""
    global rpi_internal_temp
    rpi_internal_temp = CPUTemperature().temperature


def c2f(temperature_c):
    """Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit"""
    return temperature_c * (9 / 5) + 32


def lcd_display_data_controller():
    """Display various measurments and data on the small LCD. Switch every (display_info_delay) seconds."""
    global killswitch, display_info_delay
    global dht_fog_chamber_error, dht_grow_area_error, dht_root_chamber_error
    global temp_roots, humidity_roots, pressure_roots
    global temp_grow, humidity_grow
    global temp_nutrient_solution, humidity_nutrient_mist
    
    while killswitch==False:
        reset_clear_lcd()
        
        # For testing purpose
        #lcd.message("New round.")
        #sleep(display_info_delay)
        #reset_clear_lcd()

        # Root temperature and humidity
        if dht_root_chamber_error==False:
            lcd.message = (
            "R1: {:.1f}C/{:.1f}F \nHumidity: {}% ".format(
                temp_roots, c2f(temp_roots), humidity_roots
                )
            )
            sleep(display_info_delay)
            reset_clear_lcd()
        else:
            lcd.message = ("ERROR: DHT root\nchamber!")
            sleep(display_info_delay)
            reset_clear_lcd()


        # Root pressure
        lcd.message = (
            "Root pressure:\n{:.1f} hPa".format(
                pressure_roots
            )
        )
        sleep(display_info_delay)
        reset_clear_lcd()

        # Crop grow area temperature and humidity
        if dht_grow_area_error==False:    
            lcd.message = (
                "G:{:.1f}C/{:.1f}F \nHumidity: {}% ".format(
                    temp_grow, c2f(temp_grow), humidity_grow
                )
            )
            sleep(display_info_delay)
            reset_clear_lcd()
        else:
            lcd.message = ("ERROR: DHT grow\narea!")
            sleep(display_info_delay)
            reset_clear_lcd()


        # Nutrient liquid temperature   
        lcd.message = (
            "F nutrient temp.\n{:.1f}C/{:.1f}F ".format(
                temp_nutrient_solution, c2f(temp_nutrient_solution)
            )
        )
        sleep(display_info_delay)
        reset_clear_lcd()      


        # Nutrient mist temperature and humidity
        if dht_fog_chamber_error==False:
            lcd.message = (
            "F: {:.1f}C/{:.1f}F \nHumidity: {}% ".format(
                temp_nutrient_mist, c2f(temp_nutrient_mist), humidity_nutrient_mist
                )
            )
            sleep(display_info_delay)
            reset_clear_lcd()
        else:
            lcd.message = ("ERROR: DHT fog\nchamber!")
            sleep(display_info_delay)
            reset_clear_lcd()

            
        # Raspberry Pi internal temperature  
        lcd.message = (
            "R Pi (int. temp): \n{:.1f}C/{:.1f}F ".format(
                rpi_internal_temp, c2f(rpi_internal_temp)
            )
        )
        sleep(display_info_delay)
        reset_clear_lcd()


def kill_processes(): 
    """ToDo: A button must be pressed which gracefully kills all processes preparing for shutdown."""
    # Power off machines
    GPIO.output(relay_fogger, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(relay_led, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(relay_oxygen, GPIO.LOW)
    
    # Joined the threads / stop the threads after killswitch is true - Shutdown order is very important
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    t3.join()
    t4.join()
    t5.join()
    t6.join()
    t8.join()
    t9.join()
    t10.join()
    t7.join() # display thread last to die
    #tx.join() 
    reset_clear_lcd()
    
    # Stop message
    lcd.message = 'Full stop.\nOk to shut down.'
    
    # GPIO clearing
    GPIO.cleanup()


###################################
# Thread setup - Startup order is important
###################################
#tx = threading.Thread(target=xx, args=(killswitch,sleep_fogger,))
#tx = threading.Thread(target=killswitch_button)
t1 = threading.Thread(target=get_rpi_temp)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=get_temp_nutrient_solution)
t3 = threading.Thread(target=get_temp_humidity_nutrient_mist)
t4 = threading.Thread(target=get_temp_humidity_root_chamber)
t5 = threading.Thread(target=get_pressure_root_chamber)
t6 = threading.Thread(target=get_temp_humidity_grow_area)
t7 = threading.Thread(target=lcd_display_data_controller)
t8 = threading.Thread(target=relay_fogger_control)
t9 = threading.Thread(target=relay_oxygen_control)
t10 = threading.Thread(target=relay_heatled_control)

 
# Start the threads
t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
t4.start()
t5.start()
t6.start()

sleep(2) # Give everything a bit extra time before the LCD starts displaying data

t7.start()
t8.start()
t9.start()
t10.start()
#tx.start()




###################################
# Code main process---
###################################
while not killswitch:
    sleep(1)




###################################
# Graceful exit
kill_processes()
###################################
```

Now, the relevant parts are below.

```
# Define the killswitch push button
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

def button_callback(channel):
    """When the button is pressed."""
    global killswitch
    # Due to serious issues with false positives regarding button being pushed
    start_time = time.time()
    
    while GPIO.input(channel) == 0: # Wait for button up
        pass
    
    buttonTime = time.time() - start_time
    
    if buttonTime >= .1:
        print("###########\nKillswitch button was pressed!\n###########")
        killswitch = True

# Init the button
GPIO.add_event_detect(12, GPIO.RISING, callback=button_callback, bouncetime=150)
#GPIO.add_event_detect(12, GPIO.FALLING, callback=button_callback, bouncetime=500)


def kill_processes(): 
    """ToDo: A button must be pressed which gracefully kills all processes preparing for shutdown."""
    # Power off machines
    GPIO.output(relay_fogger, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(relay_led, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(relay_oxygen, GPIO.LOW)
    
    # Joined the threads / stop the threads after killswitch is true - Shutdown order is very important
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    t3.join()
    t4.join()
    t5.join()
    t6.join()
    t8.join()
    t9.join()
    t10.join()
    t7.join() # display thread last to die
    #tx.join() 
    reset_clear_lcd()
    
    # Stop message
    lcd.message = 'Full stop.\nOk to shut down.'
    
    # GPIO clearing
    GPIO.cleanup()


###################################
# Thread setup - Startup order is important
###################################
#tx = threading.Thread(target=xx, args=(killswitch,sleep_fogger,))
#tx = threading.Thread(target=killswitch_button)
t1 = threading.Thread(target=get_rpi_temp)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=get_temp_nutrient_solution)
t3 = threading.Thread(target=get_temp_humidity_nutrient_mist)
t4 = threading.Thread(target=get_temp_humidity_root_chamber)
t5 = threading.Thread(target=get_pressure_root_chamber)
t6 = threading.Thread(target=get_temp_humidity_grow_area)
t7 = threading.Thread(target=lcd_display_data_controller)
t8 = threading.Thread(target=relay_fogger_control)
t9 = threading.Thread(target=relay_oxygen_control)
t10 = threading.Thread(target=relay_heatled_control)

 
# Start the threads
t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
t4.start()
t5.start()
t6.start()

sleep(2) # Give everything a bit extra time before the LCD starts displaying data

t7.start()
t8.start()
t9.start()
t10.start()
#tx.start()




###################################
# Code main process---
###################################
while not killswitch:
    sleep(1)




###################################
# Graceful exit
kill_processes()
###################################
```

Can anyone see where the error lies in or what I must change in order to make this work? As it is now, if I push the button nothing happens, no matter if I push it briefly or hold it.

Comment: Problems like this are usually hardware related. Bad switch/cables/connections or even interference from other components. Have you already tried rooting out a hardware issue?

Comment: Hi @Cube. Yes, I have tried to root out any issues with cabling and am quite sure that nothing is wrong there. Can the relays be interfering? I don't think so since every tutorial I followed carefully. I am not sure if I can do something with the Raspberry Pi itself?

Comment: relays shouldn't interfere. AC currents or other high frequency components (data transfers, etc.)  might lead to interference, but only if they are really close to your button.
If you have pin connections (where you stick a pin into a connector), like on a breadboard, they can be slightly lose and disconnect spontaneously. This can happen with lower quality cheap components.

Comment: @Cube, then I will change the button placement and see if that will help. What is really strange is that I should be able to filter out unwanted false positives with a bit of code. Like a button press should take more time than a random noise signal, I guess?